# How to insert 2 SIM cards on Ulefone Armor 9?

Tags: dual-sim, ulefone

I have the [Ulefone Armor 9](https://www.gsmarena.com/ulefone_armor_9-10322.php). It states it has a Hybrid Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by). In the settings, it seems it says there are 2 slots for SIM cards. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to put in 2 SIM cards.

Opening the slot seems there's only a place for 1.

[image]

[image]

Has anyone seen this before? How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hybrid dual SIM slot is a technology that offers both features of a SIM card and a MicroSD card.

The hybrid dual SIM slot also means the OEM provided just two spaces instead of the traditional three slots for dual SIM cards and a MicroSD card. In other words, either two SIM cards are used or one SIM card slot is sacrificed to serve the role of a MicroSD slot.

Simply put, you have two options:

1. Dual SIM (one micro/nano SIM + one micro/nano SIM)
2. One micro/nano SIM + MicroSD card

Comment: ah ok, thanks! How do I open the right hand side to put in the sim/sd?

Answer (score 0):

To open the second slot, push the pin-like end of the tool that's supplied with the phone (or a needle or other small pin) into the tiny hole at the end of the secondary cover.